# prove $\frac{1}{2\pi i}dz/z$ is the generator of $H^1(\Bbb{P}^1\setminus \{0,\infty\},\Bbb{Z})$

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, solution-verification, complex-geometry

I was trying to prove that the singular cohomology $H^1(\Bbb{P}^1\setminus \{0,\infty\},\Bbb{Z})$ has a deRham representative $dz/z$. That is $\frac{1}{2\pi i}dz/z \in H^1(\Bbb{P}^1\setminus \{0,\infty\},\Bbb{Z})$ will generate this group (notice that by the MV sequence we have $H^1(\Bbb{P}^1\setminus \{0,\infty\},\Bbb{Z}) \cong \Bbb{Z}$ )

---

what I have done so far, first $dz/z$ is a well defined smooth form on $\Bbb{P}^1\setminus \{0,\infty\}$, and we know the generator of $H_1(\Bbb{P}^1\setminus \{0,\infty\},\Bbb{Z})$ should be a closed loop winding around the origin 1 time. and we know that $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma dz/z = 1$ for this generator $\gamma$, and the integral is independent of the representative element $\gamma \in H^1(\Bbb{P}^1\setminus \{0,\infty\},\Bbb{Z})$. Now I want to combine these observations together.

First represent $\gamma$ by the fundamental class $[\gamma] \in H^{2-1}_{\text{dR}}(\Bbb{P}^1\setminus \{0,\infty\},\Bbb{Z})$ such that :

$$\int_{\Bbb{P^1}\setminus \{0,\infty\}}[\gamma]\cup \alpha = \int_{\gamma}\alpha$$ for any 1-form $\alpha$

Second we take the Poincare duality of $[\gamma]$ gets unique 1-form $\beta$ such that $$\int_{\Bbb{P}^1\setminus \{0,\infty\},\Bbb{Z})} [\gamma]\cup \beta = \int_\gamma \beta = 1$$ and we see $\frac{1}{2\pi i}dz/z$ is this one. therefore $\frac{1}{2\pi i}dz/z$ will generate $H^1(\Bbb{P}^1\setminus \{0,\infty\},\Bbb{Z})$, is my understanding correct?

Comment: «We know that generator of $H^1/(P^1,\{0,\infty\},\mathbb Z)$
 should be a closed loop winding around the origin 1 time»: this does not make any sense, for the elements of cohomology are not (classes of) loops!

Comment: thank you @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez , I know my proof is not very rigorous , I know we should use this fact? this is the generator of the homology

Comment: Apart from that, the class of $dz/z$ is not an element of $H^1(blah,\mathbb Z)$: you have to divideby $2\pi i$ to get an integer valued cocycle that is in there.

Comment: To do this correctly you need to be explicit about how are you looking at elements of de Rham cohomology $H_{dR}^*(X)$ (such as the class of $dz/z$) as elements of cohomology with integer values $H^*(X,\mathbb Z)$. The two things are very different things.

Comment: I haven't learnt enough algebraic topology, the fundamental class $[\gamma]$ lies in $H^1(X,\Bbb{Z})$ which will be the generator of this cohomology, since $\gamma$ is generator of $H_1(X,\Bbb{Z})$?